# Copy and Insert a Range If Cell Contains a Keyword

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of data about questions and their answers. It is poorly formatted. I am organizing the questions and answers.

I am trying to copy a range if cell i of column N contain keyword "Question".
If cell of column N contain keyword "Question" then I need to copy a range from next cell to ninth cell of column N to Column Y.
So, my range for copying is Range(i+1, N : i+9, Y).

Once, it is copied I need to insert that Range after a eighth cell in Column A that has keyword "Question".
So, my inserting range is Range(i+9, A : i+17, A).

I wrote the following code.

```vb
Sub OrganizingQuestion()
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim que As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
For iRow = 1 To Range("N" & "5000").End(xlUp).Row Step 1
    If Cells(iRow, 14) = "Question" Then
        Set rng = Range("N" & iRow + 1 & ":Y" & iRow + 9)
        rng.Copy
    End If
   
    If Cells(iRow, 1) = "Question" Then
        Set rng2 = Range("A" & iRow + 9 & ":A" & iRow + 18)
        rng2.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=rng
    End If
Next iRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CopyOrigin is takes an XlInsertFormatOrigin enumeration value.  I never use it.

[image]

```
Sub OrganizingQuestion()
    Dim iRow As Integer

    For iRow = 1 To Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Step 1

        If Cells(iRow, 14) = "Question" And Cells(iRow, 1) = "Question" Then
            Range("N" & iRow + 1 & ":Y" & iRow + 9).Copy
            Range("A" & iRow + 9 & ":A" & iRow + 18).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If

    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: I know its Range but I meant is it the first we are copying? I think it is.

Comment: Sorry about that I forgot to remove that line.  I just consolidated your code.  Those are your ranges.  The rng and rng2 variables seemed like fluff to me.  That did nothing to add to the readability of the code, so I removed them.  The only problem that I seen with your code was the CopyOrigin parameter.

Comment: In my case, iRow for `Question` are different. But with very little modifications your solution worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I agree with you. Using CopyOrigin was incorrect. Thank you for pointing out the problem and providing the solution.

Comment: Glad that I was able to help.  Thanks for the check.